# Getting an error message when putting Laravel test project online

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel

I am getting this message when I attempt to put my site up online

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Error rendering view: [home.index]

Trying to get property of non-object
Location:

/home/bluelynx/public_html/storage/views/4f62cf9f53fafa06c72f532abef2ee2b on line 161
Stack Trace:

#0 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(42): Laravel\Error::native(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/home/bluelynx/...', 161)
#1 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/view.php(386) : eval()'d code(161): Laravel\{closure}(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/home/bluelynx/...', 161, Array)
#2 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/view.php(386): eval()
#3 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/blade.php(71): Laravel\View->get()
#4 [internal function]: Laravel\{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))
#5 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/event.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/event.php(138): Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)
#7 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/view.php(348): Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)
#8 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/view.php(590): Laravel\View->render()
#9 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/response.php(268): Laravel\View->__toString()
#10 /home/bluelynx/public_html/laravel/laravel.php(180): Laravel\Response->render()
#11 /home/bluelynx/public_html/public/index.php(34): require('/home/bluelynx/...')
#12 {main}
```

This is just to make sure I can get this live before continuing using this framework. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of PHP is there?

Comment: The php version is 5.3.25

Comment: Have you edited anything? Can you please post the code of `home.index` view?

Comment: OK, I got it...I thought I commented out database connections but i didnt lol thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Had blade db connections inside forgot to comment out